# error while setting a fact or debug a webpage after registering this webpage in the get_uri module in Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I have a problem every time while setting a fact for a registered webpage the error is :

u'redirected': False}]}: template error while templating string: unexpected char u'&' at 1238

The Playbook like:

```
 - name: check webpage
   uri:
     url: http://{{ item.host }}.x.x.x
     validate_certs: False 
     return_content: yes
     status_code: 200
   register: webpage3
   with_items: "{{ servers }}"
   when: 
   - lb is defined 
   - lb == "true"

   - name: debug webpage
     set_fact: 
     fact: "{{ webpage3 }}"
     when: 
     - lb is defined
     ignore_errors: yes
```

and my ansible version is ansible 2.2.1.0

So, do I have a problem with my webpage itself and is there's a solution to skip this error?

and after troubleshooting, I figured out that it fails because of a line starts with

```html
    <!-->
```

so how to skip this line with this character?

Comment: can you debug the output and also try to change the identification for `fact`

Comment: both tried even debug with msg the same output set fact to result_new for example but the same output

Comment: Please show the actual error output in a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I have solved it by providing the dest in the uri module to a file then using sed to remove the unwanted characters and then registering the output to a new value to set_fact from and finally greping the needed value using a grep command. as it was hard to skip those chars in output